# What is this glue layer on top of the slate stone flooring?

Tags: flooring, adhesive, carpet, stone

I ripped off the carpet which was installed on top of the slate stone flooring sometime back. I saw a layer of "glue-like"

[image]

[image]

I assume it is for the carpet to glue down, which it did not even do its job (it was very lose).

Question is How do I scrape off this layer of glue, given that it is very sticky to the stone but NOT at all to the carpet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mesh was a heat activated glue strip to join carpet usually found at doorways and if the room was wider than the roll 2 pieces are butted together and a iron that heats the glue and carpet is used to melt the glue and make a seam. Some of the heated glue sticks to the floor but it is used for the splice. Most places use 4" wide but I prefer 6" as it holds better.  This stuff releases with heat a heat gun is what I use but a hair dryer on high heat low air flow may be hot enough. A razor scraper will shave and left over glue, and a bit of heat makes it softer (think hot glue gun) for the type of glue used.

Comment: Now looking at it again there are three layers. The top looking like fiberglass is obviously glue. The bottom is stone. But what is the middle layer? I am wondering if this is not natural but some "fake" stone looking materials.

Comment: The stuff I use has a paper or some type of flexible membrane on the bottom then a fiberglass mesh that is coated in the glue it comes on rolls and some of the glue gets on the back side of the paper when heated it sticks to the floor or I think this is what you are seeing. If there is something below that it may be the original flooring.

Comment: Oh so the top 2 layers must be removed then. It seems very thick, almost like 1/4" total.

Comment: It may have been a self leveling compound I cannot tell from the photo. I would check the thickness in another area , this or was a tapered mortar to adjust for different heights of the 2 rooms.